# (Liouville’s Theorem) find holomorphic f such that $|f(z)| \leq |z|^k$ for all $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am completely stuck on this question. I found in earlier part of the question that if $|f(z)| \leq M|z|^k$ then f(z) is a polynomial of degree at most k.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(z)=\sum_{k\geqslant 0}a_k z^k$ be the Taylor expansion around $0$. This converges all over $\Bbb C$, and for  a simple closed curve around the origin, for example $\gamma$ a circle of radius $R$ and center $0$, $$a_k=\frac{k!}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{k+1}}d\zeta$$

Now use the standard estimate to show $a_j=0$ when $j>k$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $g(z) := \frac{f(z)}{z^k}$. Because $|g(z)| \leq M$ and $g(z)$ is holomorphic away from $0$, [the singularity at the origin is removable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity#Riemann.27s_theorem), hence $g(z)$ can be made holomorphic on the entire plane. What can you say now?